# Firefox won't change page when trying a different URL

Tags: firefox

I'm posting this with the hope to find an active Firefox developer to help troubleshoot a nasty bug.  When using the Firefox browser with my web application, the page sticks within the tab and doesn't want to change.  Clicking links to navigate off the page or just changing the address in the bar doesn't leave the page.  This only happens in Firefox.  Here's a screencast of the issue.

http://screencast.com/t/Xr662nAr

I can give a developer access (private message) to the application to help troubleshoot this issue.  At the moment, we have to tell our clients to stay away from the Firefox browser when using our application or deal with this issue until it is resolved.  We have no such problems with Chrome.  So far I've been able to replicate this on both windows and linux.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the problematic code **in the body of the question**; otherwise, this is off-topic.

Comment: If I knew where the problematic code was, I would have posted it.  This is a web application with javascript that runs perfectly well in chrome.  There's an apparent bug in the firefox browser somewhere and I am posting this with the hope that I can help a developer on the FF team locate what is causing the issue itself.